В запросах к новой таблице - "недопустимое имя объекта SQL Server", с другими таблицами всё хорошо
У меня есть несколько таблиц в этой же БД и с ними все запросы отлично работают, создал новую таблицу через CREATE и указание столбцов, ничего больше - при формировании запросов она сама и ее столбцы помечаются как недопустимые объекты, даже когда нажимаю на саму таблицу и создаю к ней запрос типа такого:
USE [MSCompleX]
GO  

SELECT [Id]
      ,[INN]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Contact Person]
      ,[Password]
      ,[Login]
      ,[IsAdmin]
  FROM [dbo].[UsersNew]

GO

Делал запрос HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('dbo.UsersNew', 'OBJECT', 'SELECT'); - возвращает 1. Хочу понять чем эта таблица отличается от остальных.

Если речь про программу SQL Server Management Studio, то у неё просто есть кэш, который автоматически не обновляется. Но есть волшебное сочетание клавиш для обновления кэша Ctrl+Shift+R нажмите это сочетание клавиш и подождите пару секунд. Красная подсветка должна исчезнуть.

Спасибо, помогло. Но я думал о возможности чего-то подобного, пробовал отключаться от БД и подключаться обратно, как мне казалось это должно было решить все подобные проблемы.

Как вариант возможно правой кнопкой нажать на вашу БД и выбрать Refresh тоже должно работать. Что реконнект непомогает, это, конечно, стрёмно, но зато реконнект с кэшэм делается быстрее, чем если бы кэша не было. Программе пришлось бы опять все объекты БД заново читать, сам интерфейс просто долго бы ждать пришлось, если база большая.
